Сообщение отправляется в чат, но если это супер группа, как указать конкретную ветку? ведь она имеет chat_id и id конкретной ветки
async def send_post():
    logger.info("Sending post...")
    tickers = await get_crypto_data()
    market_data = await get_market_data()
    date = datetime.now(TIMEZONE).strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    message = format_message(tickers, market_data, date)
    screenshot = await get_screenshot()

    if llm_rewrite_enabled:
        try:
            message = await rewrite_message_with_llm(message)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error in LLM rewrite: {e}")

    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, reply_to=37378, photo=screenshot, caption=message[:1024], parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN)
    logger.info("Post sent successfully."

Попробовал через reply, не прокатило

не очень понятно о чём речь. Можно более развёрнуто?

Бот отправляет сообщение в группу тг c нужным Chat_id. С обычными группами все ок, но если это супер группа(имеет несколько веток), как отправить в нужную ветку? общий id ветки #-1001722510965_37378  . Но сообщение отправляется все равно в -1001722510965

@Роматюриков для этого есть параметр message_thread_id. Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Да, но он выдает ошибку Error sending test post: Bot.send_photo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message_thread_id'

В общем, помогло:
reply_to_message_id=CHANNEL_ID1`

где CHANNEL_ID1 указывается id чата после _
